# Fatal error while installing magento on a server

Tags: magento

To run magento module on a server, I transfer all the files in my server through ftp, After completely transfer, i got this error

> "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract' not found
>   in
>   public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Store.php"

Comment: Did you followed these steps while transferring [Link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-move-your-website-from-one-domain-to-another.html). This might help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to: `/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db` 
directory and look for `Abstract.php` file.

It seems that the file was missed. If `Abstract.php` does not present in the said directory, **copy/upload** the file from a fresh Magento installation (**Magento version should be same as the current installation**).

Not all of your files could of successfully transferred through FTP.

Comment: It's best to use a tarball to do a full site transfer. FTP has timeout issues, you don't know how many files got missed.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Magento Cleanup tool, it could be that your file Permissions got messed up somehow.

Read more about it here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions